# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use - Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn, python-huey

[image]

I'm trying to deploy a project https://github.com/kc1/flask-huey-example to heroku to allow usage of a task queue and flask. The project layout is as above. You can also take a look at the github repo which I have updated. The project is running without issue locally on windows (gunicorn is not used locally) .

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn run_app:app
worker: python /app/.heroku/python/bin/huey_consumer run_huey.huey
```

I had previously gotten an error [Failed to find application object 'app' in 'run_app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880993/failed-to-find-application-object-app-in-run-app) . I tried to fix that by changing run_app.py to:

```
from app import create_app, config

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import logging
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='localhost', port=6060, debug=True)


else:


    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Unfortunately , now when I push to heroku, I see:

```
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253114+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-16 16:37:59 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253118+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253121+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253123+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253124+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253126+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253128+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253130+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253132+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253133+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253135+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253137+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253139+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253140+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253142+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253144+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253146+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/run_app.py", line 21, in <module>
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253148+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.run(debug=False)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253149+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253151+00:00 app[web.1]:     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253153+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253155+00:00 app[web.1]:     inner()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253157+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 774, in inner
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253159+00:00 app[web.1]:     fd=fd)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 666, in make_server
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253162+00:00 app[web.1]:     passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253164+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 577, in __init__
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253165+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.address_family), handler)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253167+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253169+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.server_bind()
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253171+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253173+00:00 app[web.1]:     socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253181+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
2018-08-16T16:37:59.253183+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You cannot have two applications listening on the same port at the same time. Perhaps you started the application twice, or some other application has taken the port.

Answer (score 0):

The port you are trying to bind you application to is already being used by another app. Close the other app and re-deploy

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to run a Flask application on Heroku and solved it by removing the

```
app.run
```

statement entirely from my app file (mine is named app.py), for example your run_app.py.

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

When I want to run the app locally, I run in terminal (MacOS zsh)

```
FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```